# Validation using data annotation depending on referenced class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, data-annotations

Can I have a different validation messages depending on the class referencing my model class...

for e.g.

```
public class AdviceUnit
{
    public Client MainClient {get;set;}

    public Client PartnerClient {get;set;}

    public List<Investments> JointInvestments {get;set;}
}

public class Client
{
    public Guid Id {get;set;}

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "ERROR MESSAGE but a different ")]
    public string FirstName {get;set;}

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "client last name is missing")]
    public string LastName {get;set;}

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "client date of birth is missing")]
    public DateTime DateOfBirth {get;set;}

}
```

What I really want is a different validation error message for main & partner client.

for e.g.

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "main client first name is missing")]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "partner client first name is missing")]
```

My view is bound to AdviceUnit object.

Comment: then make partner Client a different class , you can inherit the Client class and keep it identical - with jst a data validation attribute being the difference .   But ... what you really should do is handle these validation messages in javascript.  the whole point of c# validation is a last point to check the data before it goes in db - not to give specific client messages like this

Comment: Yeah, I suppose I could inherit client class and create a new partner class but if there is a better way of doing this without creating two different classes that would be great. This is just a simple validation, we have lot of other validation happening on the server side anyway so I don't really want to write any javascript just for that.

Comment: Create a ValidationAttribute that uses reflection to get the class name and produce the validation message that way?

Answer (score 1):

Like BDH has said (sorry I wasn't stealing your answer, credit goes to BDH for posting the comment first), you could implement a custom required validation attribute.

As a proof of concept:

1. Add a property of type 'ClientType' string to the Client class, set this to 'Main' or 'Partner'. This property will be retrieved during validation:

> ```
>  public string ClientType {get; set;}
> ```

2. Implement custom required attribute and set a replace key:

> ```
> public class CustomRequiredAttribute : RequiredAttribute
> {
>     protected override ValidationResult IsValid
>       (object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
>     {
>         var instance = validationContext.ObjectInstance;
>         var instancePropertyValue = instance.GetType().GetProperty("ClientType").GetValue(instance, null);
>         return new ValidationResult(ErrorMessage.Replace("[replaceText]" ,instancePropertyValue.ToString()));
>     }
> }
> ```

3. Use the CustomRequiredAttribute, using the replace key:

> ```
> [CustomRequired(ErrorMessage = "[replaceText] client first name is missing ")]
> public string FirstName {get;set;}
> ```

Only caveat is that the ClientType property must be set before posting/validation occurs.

Comment: Thanks everyone.. especially BDH and uv_man...
I was aware of this approach, I have actually implemented exactly the same thing previously where I have a custom validation attribute to compare two different properties of the same class. I thought if there is something already built into .net framework so I can avoid creating custom attrbiute.